# p4v automatically sync to head on start-up

Tags: perforce, p4v

Is there a way I can configure my p4v installation on windows to automatically sync all the files in my client to latest revision whenever I launch the viewer?

I am asking this because I do not want to worry about syncing to "head" every time I want to open a file using p4v.

Comment: Forcibly syncing (and dealing with merge conflicts) when you might not want to sync sounds like a bad idea.  Doing it whenever you launch p4v isn't going to solve your problem anyway; what if the file changes while you happen to have p4v already open?

Comment: As an alternative approach, I often configure some of my machines with a "cron" job or "Windows Scheduled Task" which runs "p4 sync" each night at, say, midnight, and then does a complete build of the code. Then when I come in each morning, that workspace is nicely up to date with yesterday's changes. Of course, I don't use that workspace for my regular daily work, just for testing and debugging already-committed work, so I don't have to deal with the merge conflicts that @jamesdlin mentions.

Comment: Ok. I understand the idea of setting up a cron-job to do the every-day syncing. But can I configure p4V windows client so that it syncs the files in my workspace (and not just check for pending updates)? Let us assume that  "merge-conflicts" are not an issue since the files concerned are only documents that I will be simply reading and not editing.

Comment: @user3282982 If you truly want this, you could write a script that executes the `p4` command-line program to sync the desired client and then runs `p4v`.

Comment: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**. You may be able to get help on Super User."...  To which Perforce I think would qualify, what is programming these days without proper source control.

Answer (score 2):

You can select the "Automatically get all revisions" option on the workspace in question.  From p4v edit the workspace, it is on the basic tab at the bottom.

[image: The Edit Workspace Window]